# adding event listener on collection

Tags: javascript, events

if I have a collection that has the same class, how can I add an onclick event listener without effecting each item with that class.

```
<div class = "overlay">etc. etc.</div>
<div class = "overlay">etc. etc.</div>
<div class = "overlay">etc. etc.</div>
<div class = "overlay">etc. etc.</div>
```

I'd want to run the following but only effect the one I click...not all of them with the classname 'overlay':

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")
x.addEventListener("click", function() { this.addClassName("hide"); } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function() { this.classList.add("hide"); })
}
```

Comment: is this the only way to do this?  Someone mentioned to me a way of binding the click event to the target without having to loop through

Comment: With pure JavaScript this is the best way but with jQuery you can do that by single selector no need any iterate: $('.overlay').click(function(){ $(this).addClass("hide");})